# AIR 3.1 Application unable to connect to localhost or local IP Address

Tags: actionscript-3, security, air, localhost, sandbox

I am building an AIR application using AIR 3.1 that is trying to connect to a local http socket using

```
    localhost:7676
```

The socket is being run from an OSX application on the same computer that the AIR app is trying to connect to using localhost.  Upon successful connection the AIR app is supposed to receive a JSON string of data.

When running the swf in a browser, I connect using localhost:7676 there is no issue, it connects successfully to the OSX app running the socket.  When the FlashBuilder project is packaged up and compiled as an AIR app, and I connect using the same address, I get this error, and don't know how to resolve...

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to localhost:7676 halted - not permitted from app:/Matrx_Remote_App.swf
SecurityError: Error #2147: Forbidden protocol in URL localhost:7676

The code that I am using in the class is just a simple loader class

```
    _loader = new URLLoader();

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:7676");
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioerrorHandler);
        _loader.addEventListener(flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, handleOnEventStatus);
        _loader.load(request);
```

And the onComplete method looks like this:

```
    private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
        trace("e " + URLLoader(e.target).data +  _loader.data + " _loader.bytesTotal " + _loader.bytesTotal);
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        var jsonData:Object  = JSON.parse(loader.data);
        trace(jsonData);

    }
```

ANY help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can find an answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304271/security-sandbox-in-as3

Comment: Are you running the air app on the same machine that is works on?

Comment: I am running the air app on the same machine, that is correct.

Comment: @Eran thanks for the response - I added the -use-network=false to the Additional Compiler Arguments in the Properties of the Flash Builder project and I still get the same message.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You're loading a local file, something that's not permitted. However, as you're developing this you can of course allow this.

Add your project folder to the trusted locations: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: this is an AIR app and I don't think the same rules apply, as I tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Update to this question.... AS it turns out, it was a problem with the way the socket was written and had nothing to do with the client side, thanks to everyone who took the time to help